# Shared Windows hosting, asp.net :Getting Security Exception when trustlevel changed to medium

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, shared-hosting

I have hosted my website with Speedhost.in. Recently they changed the default setting for all web-apps from full to medium. I am getting a Security Exception since then. My hosting company has restricted overriding of trustlevel policy and so I cannot change the trustlevel to full again.

The security exception I am getting is more of a general exception and I am unable to think of a way to fix this. How should I decide which dll is asking for the restricted permission?

[image: Exception Stack Trace]

Answer (score 0):

Post changing of the trust level in the hosting(Medium trust level) looks like some dependency like Ninject are not working..you need to change this Ninject dependency from full to medium...by updating that